# How to plot one column vs the rest in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-columns, scatter-plot

I have a data set where the [,1] is time and then the next 14 are magnitudes. I would like to scatter plot all the magnitudes vs time on one graph, where each different column is gridded (layered on top of one another)

I want to use the raw data to make these graphs and came make them separately but would like to only have to do this process once.

data set called A, the only independent variable is time (the first column)

```
df<-data.frame(time=A[,1],V11=A[,2],V08=A[,3],
 V21=A[,4],V04=A[,5],V22=A[,6],V23=A[,7],
 V24=A[,8],V25=A[,9],V07=A[,10],xxx=A[,11],
 V26=A[,12],PV2=A[,13],V27=A[,14],V28=A[,15],
 NV1=A[,16])
```

I tried the code mentioned by @VlooO but it scrunched the graphs making them too hard to decipher and each had its own axes. All my graphs can be on the same axes just separated by their headings.

When looking at the ggplots I Think that would be a perfect program for what I want.

```
ggplot(data=df.melt,aes(x=time,y=???))
```

I confused what my y should be since I want to reference each different column.

Thanks R community

Comment: you could exploit `reshape2::melt` to convert data in long format, then use `ggplot` to plot Time on the x and the column of value on the y axis, using `color` for grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Hope i understand you correctly:

```
df<-data.frame(time=rnorm(10),A=rnorm(10),B=rnorm(10),C=rnorm(10))

par(mfrow=c(length(df)-1,1))
sapply(2:length(df), function(x){
  plot(df[,c(1,x)])
})
```

The result would be

[image: Rplot]

Comment: This worked great for only three columns though. When I tried to apply to the rest of the columns at once when I tried to plot it I was given the error of _figure margins too large_. this is what my df ended up looking like:`df<-data.frame(time=data[,1],V11=data[,2],V08=data[,3],
V21=data[,4],V04=data[,5],V22=data[,6],V23=data[,7],
V24=data[,8],V25=data[,9],V07=data[,10],xxx=data[,11],
V26=data[,12],PV2=data[,13],V27=data[,14],V28=data[,15],
NV1=data[,16])` @FlooO Perhaps I should change the size of the matrix, if so Could you help clarify where to put the new diminto `par(mfrow...` command?

Comment: the `par(mfrow=...)` creates a grid of the dimensions of `mfrow` so in the above example `mfrow=(14,1)` means 14 rows and 1 column if you think of a matrix. making it 5x3 or 4x4 might work. Also check our `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))` to change the margins of you plots. Change the `c(1,1,1,1)` to your needs

Answer (score 3):

here some hints since you don't provide a reproducible example , neither you show what you have tried :

1. Use `list.files` to go through all your documents
2. Use `lapply` to loop over the result of the previous step and read your data
3. Put your data in the long format using `melt` from `reshape2` and the variable time as id.
4. Use `ggplot2` to plot using the variable as `aes` color/group.

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(reshape2)
   invisible(lapply(list.files(pattern=...),{
         dt = read.table(x)
         dt.l = melt(dt,id.vars='time')
         print(ggplot(dt.l)+geom_line(aes(x=time,y=value,color=variable))
       }))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need ggplot2, then the `matplot` function for base graphics can be used to do what you want in one command.

Comment: I came here looking for something like `dt[,matplot(x,y=rest_of_columns)]` instead of having to write `matplot(dt$x,dt[,!"x",with=F])`; is there a way to specifiy `rest_of_columns` that anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
After looking through a bunch more problems and playing around a bit more with ggplot2 I found a code that works pretty great. After I made my data frame (stated above), here is what i did

```
> df.m<- melt(df,"time")
ggplot(df.m, aes(time, value, colour = variable)) + geom_line() +
+ facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 2)
```

I would post the image but I don't have enough reputation points yet.

I still don't really understand why "value" is placed into the y position in aes(time, value,...) If anyone could provided an explanation that would be greatly appreciated. My last question is if anyones knows how to make the subgraphs titles smaller.

Can I use cex.lab=, cex.main= in ggplot2?