# R ggplot2: use one column as x-axis and the rest as y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large df resembling the following

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 3 | 9 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 9 | 5 |
| 4 | 8 | 12 | 7 | 3 |

I am trying to make a scatter plot where column A is the x-values and all values in the rest of the columns are the y-values with each column a separate color. I have tried the following but receive the error `Error: unexpected ']' in p1`

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = df.p, aes(df.p, aes(x=colnames(df.p[1]), y = colnames(df.p[2:]), colour=df.p[2:]))) + geom_point() + scale_colour_identity()
```

I have also tried `x=get(colnames(df.p[1]))` and `x=df.p[1]` but I always get the same error

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426732/how-to-plot-one-column-vs-the-rest-in-r) but got the error

```
Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `variable`.
* Plot is missing `variable`
* Layer 1 is missing `variable`
```

Comment: Hey! I would melt the df before plotting, using `dplyr` package. E.g., `df_new<-gather(df, variable, value, -A)` and in the code `aes(x=A, y=value, color=variable)`

Comment: When I plotted it seemed to ran but no graph appeared( using Rmarkdown or in plot)  and when I ran `show(p1) I got the same error as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = " A B   C   D   E
1   10  3   9   5
2   4   6   9   5
4   8   12  7   3")

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!A) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = A, y= value, color = name)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I got the error `Error in unique(names(data)) : object 'numSam' not found` where numSam is my actual column name

Comment: ```df_new <- pivot_longer(!numSam) %>%
ggplot(df_new, aes(x = numSam, y= value, color = name)) +
geom_point()```

Comment: I tried both solutions and got the same error. Do I need to specify the df to use somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234914/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-keenan).

Comment: Okay I tried ```df.p %>% 
  pivot_longer(!numSam) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = numSam, y= value, color = name)) +
  geom_point()```